# Jsoup selecting two <div>

Tags: java, jsoup

I work on a webpage to that has a div tag  which itself has two div under it,
one div  has a class named padt-10 and  other div that has a class named txt28.
I have to extract image source of the first div, and text of the second div.

My code is work correctly, but it doesn't prints all elements of the second div!
so it really confuses me.

***This is the first Element of ezdihaar elements***
[image: THis is the first Element of ezdihaar elements]

```
Document doc;
    try {
    doc = Jsoup.connect("http://deals.souq.com/sa-ar/?id_tag=48&pid_tag=103").get();
    Elements maindiv =  doc.select("div");
    Elements ezdihaar =  maindiv.select("div.padt-10,div.txt28"); 

for(int e=0; e <ezdihaar.size();e++)
{ 

System.out.println(""+ezdihaar.get(e).select("img").attr("src")+"");
System.out.println(""+ezdihaar.get(e).select("div.txt28").text());  

}
```

Here is the output

```
http://cf3.souqcdn.com/items/item/79/54/46/8/item_L_20150520141412_7954468.jpg



2222 ريـال




http://cf1.souqcdn.com/item/2015/02/02/78/12/97/5/item_L_7812975_6807766.jpg



777 ريـال




http://cf4.souqcdn.com/items/item/78/07/88/1/item_L_20150514185244_7807881.jpg



499 ريـال




http://cf3.souqcdn.com/items/item/79/66/48/0/item_L_20150330132840_7966480.jpg



2444 ريـال




http://cf1.souqcdn.com/items/item/78/07/88/0/item_L_20150514190123_7807880.jpg





http://cf2.souqcdn.com/items/item/82/55/70/6/item_L_20150519140114_8255706.jpg



3888 ريـال




http://cf5.souqcdn.com/items/item/82/55/65/7/item_L_20150519140312_8255657.jpg





http://cf2.souqcdn.com/items/item/71/03/79/4/item_L_20150410074721_7103794.jpg



599 ريـال




http://cf5.souqcdn.com/items/item/47/50/56/8/item_L_20150519112226_4750568.jpg



1599 ريـال




http://cf4.souqcdn.com/items/item/75/02/50/0/item_L_20150524173210_7502500.jpg



388 ريـال




http://cf5.souqcdn.com/items/item/46/92/53/4/item_L_20150215134157_4692534.jpg



1499 ريـال




http://cf1.souqcdn.com/items/item/71/82/45/2/item_L_20150414133124_7182452.jpg



699 ريـال




http://cf3.souqcdn.com/items/item/81/60/51/2/item_L_20150519052020_8160512.jpg



2099 ريـال




http://cf4.souqcdn.com/items/item/82/55/40/1/item_L_20150513125827_8255401.jpg



2333 ريـال




http://cf5.souqcdn.com/items/item/82/55/81/0/item_L_20150513125718_8255810.jpg



2666 ريـال




http://cf2.souqcdn.com/items/item/82/55/82/1/item_L_20150513125635_8255821.jpg



3299 ريـال




http://cf3.souqcdn.com/items/item/82/55/21/6/item_L_20150514083301_8255216.jpg



3033 ريـال




http://cf4.souqcdn.com/items/item/82/55/76/9/item_L_20150514083148_8255769.jpg





http://cf2.souqcdn.com/items/item/75/02/51/0/item_L_20150524173326_7502510.jpg





http://cf2.souqcdn.com/items/item/77/20/81/8/item_L_20150430090952_7720818.jpg



222 ريـال




http://cf4.souqcdn.com/item/2013/11/03/46/85/79/0/item_L_4685790_3575542.jpg





http://cf1.souqcdn.com/items/item/67/06/05/4/item_L_20150524075440_6706054.jpg



215 ريـال




http://cf4.souqcdn.com/items/item/82/55/79/5/item_L_20150514083016_8255795.jpg





http://cf5.souqcdn.com/items/item/82/55/67/3/item_L_20150513125533_8255673.jpg





http://cf2.souqcdn.com/items/item/46/30/37/7/item_L_20150115090404_4630377.jpg



555 ريـال




http://cf2.souqcdn.com/items/item/72/54/17/4/item_L_20150422054030_7254174.jpg



1999 ريـال




http://cf4.souqcdn.com/items/item/82/55/63/2/item_L_20150514082901_8255632.jpg





http://cf1.souqcdn.com/items/item/67/92/56/7/item_L_20150420062034_6792567.jpg



410 ريـال




http://cf1.souqcdn.com/items/item/82/55/78/3/item_L_20150519130204_8255783.jpg





http://cf4.souqcdn.com/items/item/76/00/93/0/item_L_20150409120758_7600930.jpg



420 ريـال




http://cf4.souqcdn.com/items/item/56/18/39/6/item_L_20150423095348_5618396.jpg



399 ريـال




http://cf2.souqcdn.com/item/2013/08/05/55/88/07/1/item_L_5588071_2620090.jpg





http://cf1.souqcdn.com/items/item/67/92/58/5/item_L_20150517095958_6792585.jpg





http://cf3.souqcdn.com/item/2014/12/21/76/63/20/0/item_L_7663200_6474359.jpg



888 ريـال




http://cf1.souqcdn.com/items/item/69/90/00/2/item_L_20150324134244_6990002.jpg



1444 ريـال




http://cf2.souqcdn.com/items/item/81/05/60/1/item_L_20150524075052_8105601.jpg





http://cf5.souqcdn.com/items/item/67/93/32/7/item_L_20150519064536_6793327.jpg



قم بإيجاد الصفقة المناسبة!
```

Comment: You only get the own `text()` of your 2nd div. Maybe there are more nested elements containing text?

Comment: yes , but what problem with that?

Comment: If you only get that `div`s `text()`, you may skip some more nested in other tags under that 2nd `div`. That's why there may some text missing. To test test that, just println `ezdihaar`.

Comment: I test it really some <div.txt28> elements are skipped !.

Comment: Try using `.html()` instead.

Comment: @JonasCz  Same problem.

Comment: Can you be specific? Which part of the screenshot is not printed?

Comment: div.txt28 Elements are printed but not all of them!